# SSH X11 forwarding put on a different monitor

Tags: ssh, x11, multi-monitor

Is there a way to use ssh and X11 forwarding with multiple monitors, such that one screen gets the remote session and one keeps the current session?

Note: In case I didn't clarify, I meant forwarding an entire session with `gnome-session` or `start-x` or similar. I knew that ssh could be used for single windows.

Answer (score 1):

ssh forwarding does not forward the entire "session" (as in "Desktop")
instead it forwards X-calls which then draw the window using your local window manager.

Comment: You are able to forward entire sessions.